# Remove array elements by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I seem to be having a brain-freeze and am unable to remove JS array elements by index. Is there something fundamentally idiotic in the below?

```
var els;
[0, 1, 3]
0: 0
1: 1
2: 3


["Colour", "Font", "Icon", "Line 1"]
0: "Colour"
1: "Font"
2: "Icon"
3: "Text"
```

All I want to do is remove the elements from the array using index positions 0, 1 and 3 (in this example) - however, when I try this using splice, it messes up the indexes.

See:

```
els.each(function(key, val) {
            console.log(key);
            req-fields.splice(key,1);
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
function removeIndex(array, index) {
    delete array[index];
    array = array.filter(function(element) {
        return element != undefined
    });
    return array;
}
```

Example

```
removeIndex([1,4,7,13,41,16],3);
=> [1,4,7,41,16]
```

Explanation

To delete an element from an array, you use the `delete` keyword. This will make the value at that index `undefined`. You then need to filter the array, and remove undefined elements.

Comment: This is the one. Surprised to have to write a custom function for something like this, but there we go. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the index of the splice for every splicing action.

```js
var fields = ["Colour", "Font", "Icon", "Line 1"],
    els = [0, 1, 3];

els.forEach(function (val, i) {
    fields.splice(val - i, 1);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(fields, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Variation on Richard Hamilton's. Note that both of ours will return a *new* array, not actually modify the original array object.

```
function removeIndexes(array, indexes) {
    return array.filter(function(element, i) {
        return indexes.indexOf(i) === -1;
    });
}
```

Comment: Richard Hamilton's modify the original: delete array[index] leaves a hole in the original array. var a = [0,1,2,3]; delete a[2]; a becomes [0,1, empty, 3]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you remove element 0, the array gets shifted down by 1 and your other elements are in the wrong positions.  One way to solve this would be to sort your input `els` array in descending order so it will pop element 3, then 1, then 0.

```
els.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

els.each(function(key, val) {
        console.log(key);
        req-fields.splice(key,1);
    });
```